# CHARINDEX to skip over comments

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use STUFF w/ CHARINDEX to update a specific part of a string. I'm locating the '@recipients' tag and adding another email on to the end. It seems to be working correctly expect on string has a '--@recipients' and a '@recipients' and it keeps adding to the commented portion. Is there a way to skip over the commented part to insert it into the correct spot?

This is my current code.

```
STUFF(sjs.command, (CHARINDEX(',', sjs.command, CHARINDEX('@recipients', 
sjs.command)) - 1), 1, ';alerts@companyname.com''')
```

Comment: What there in sjs.command?

Comment: sjs.command is just a long string with profile_name, recipients, subject. Basically a bunch of email fields that are generated. @PriyankJ

Answer (score 1):

You can skip over --@recipients, if there a white-space or some other character for that matter in front on @recipients. Then you can modify your STUFF to check for ' @recipients' as below.

```
STUFF(sjs.command, (CHARINDEX(',', sjs.command, CHARINDEX(' @recipients', 
sjs.command)) - 1), 1, ';alerts@companyname.com''')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove everything between `--recipients` and the following `@`.  Replace `sjs.command` with the below select (swapping `@test` for `sjs.command`)

```
DECLARE @test varchar(max) = '@body=''blah'',--@recipients=''remove'',@recipients=''blah.com'',@subject=''blah'''

SELECT LEFT(@test, CHARINDEX('--@recipients', @test) -1) + RIGHT(@test, LEN(@test) - CHARINDEX('--@recipients', @test) - CHARINDEX('@', SUBSTRING(@test, CHARINDEX('--@recipients', @test) + 3, LEN(@test)))-1)
```

I like PriyankJ's answer better if there is a consistant space or character preceding the true `@recipients`.